# Secure e-mail with SMTP Virtual Server in Windows 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, email, smtp, smime

Is it possible to send **encrypted and digitally signed e-mail messages** using S/MIME through the SMTP Virtual Server component included in Windows Server 2008 or do I have to use Exchange?

If it is, what are the configuration settings required to make it work?

Thanks in advance

/Enrico

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried, but I don't see why it wouldn't be possible, since I believe it's up to the email *client* to handle encryption and signing.